# Object.keys for enum list are not getting translated at Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have declared a `.ts` file which there are some enums.
In component I am able to use to get through Object and get values for the keys but they are not translated, if I write `Object.values` there are translated but the problem then is when an enum is clicked it doesn't take the key but the value.
The language is defined at `assets/i18n`.
The key is a string.

So I have two problems.
 1. Get the keys but show the values.
 2. Translate the values but at click get the key.

Here is my code.

```
export enum Todo {
'TODO' = 'todo.TODO',
'TODO1' = 'todo.TODO1',
'TODO2' = 'todo.TODO2'
}
```

At component at I have something like this

```
public myTodo: any = {};

constructor(translateService: TranslateService){}

this.translateService.get(Object.keys(Todo)).subscribe(res => {
this.myTodo = res;
});
```

And this is my translated key.

```
"todo": {
   "TODO": "Here create Something",
   "TODO1": "Here Approve Something",
   "TODO2": "Here Decline Something"
}
```

The error it is coming always `Missing translation for key: TODO` , `Missing translation for key: TODO1`, but if I make `Object.values(Todo)` then it works but the problem it is that when I click for value then it doesn't take the `key` which in my case it is `TODO, TODO1, TODO2` but takes the value and I cannot send to backend something like this.

Comment: Uhm.. why are you assigning values inside an `enum`? I don't even know if that's legal. Why don't you use an object instead?

Comment: @CristianTraìna I have edited the enum now it is equal, but why i have assigned values inside an `enum` because so it is task.

Comment: That's not how enums work :/ You should use a set instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

or at the very least an object, not an enum

Comment: I understand you and I have looked this documentation but it wasn't helpfull, but if I change keys with values then the translate works ?
If you can provide a code to give me a idea about this I would appreciate that.